Lindenbaum's lemma and the hypotesis of deductively closure
In my lectures, we define an Henkin set for a theory $T$ as a set $H$ of enunciates in a signature $L$ that is:

Deductively closed for $T$: if $T \vdash A_1,...,A_n \Rightarrow B$ and $A_1,...,A_n \in H $, then $ B \in H$;

Rich: if  $\exists xB \in H$, then it exists a ground term $t$ s.t. $B(t/x) \in H$;

Maximal: for all $A$ enunciate, $A \in H$ or $\neg A \in H$;

Consistent: with the following equivalent definitions:
it exists an enunciate $B$ s.t. $B \notin H$, or for all enunciate $B$, $B \in H$ and $\neg B \in H$ is not acceptable at the same time.


And then we try to prove the Lindebaum's Lemma:
Suppose $S$ a set of enunciates consistent, it exists a set $S^* \supseteq S$ s.t. $S^*$ is consistent and maximal.
My question is: shouldn't we have the hypotesis that $S$ is deductively closed for $T$ in Lindenbaum's lemma? And shouldn't we use the hypotesis of closure for deduction in order to demonstrate that the two definitions of consistency for a set of enunciates are equivalent?

Why do you think that you would need the hypothesis of closure for Lindebaum's lemma? The lemma is perfectly stated and proved without it.

Because when we defined the consistency for a  set of enunciates in class, we used two definitions that we claimed are equivalent: "it exists an enunciate B s.t. B∉H , or for all enunciate B, B∈H and ¬B∈H is not acceptable at the same time", where I think we are using that this set is already deductively closed

I think my problem is related with this different definition of consistency using ∈, instead of the usual definition of consistency using ⊢

I suspect you are right. To define consistency as the existence of a statement $\phi$ that does not belong to the set assumes the set corresponds to the set of formulas deducible from a theory.
